# Can we get a Table for Two?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

### Can we get a Table for Two?

> The poker player gasps at fate;
>   He gets more than a pair of eight.
>
> To amplify her work and fun
>   Saloon girl adds a pair of one.

The answer will be two words.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No you can't, sorry, we have a

> Full House!
>  More than a pair of eight implies at least 3 8s, and a pair of 1s completes the full house of 3 8s and 2 1s. Not the best full house, but still beats a lot of hands ;)